# Android studio stop respoding when run app on real device

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, freeze

When I try to launch my app(click "Run app") on real device(Lenovo a8 s7600) Android Studio stop responding and android studio screen become black. USB debugging ON and device is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Usb debugging software according to your Lenovo model.You can it from Lenovo Official site.Also make sure you have unlock the Developer options in your device.Hope it works for you.